# Testing: react-native (expo) take snapshot of a Screen component inside of react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo, react-navigation

My test attempt currently looks like this:

```
import React from "react"

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react-native"

import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { createStore } from "redux"
import rootReducer from "src/store/reducers/root-reducer"

import ProfileScreen from "src/screens/profile"

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

test("renders correctly", async () => {
  const Screen = () => {
    // const navigationRef = React.useRef(null) // cause "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside .."
    const Stack = createStackNavigator()

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer
        // ref={navigationRef} // cause "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside .."
        >
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    )
  }

  const tree = render(<Screen />)
  await waitFor(async () => expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot())
})
```

But it keeps throwing this:

```sh
...
console.error
    The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(NavigationContainer)> component:
        in Provider (created by Screen)
        in Screen

    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit <fb link> to learn more about error boundaries
...
```

I can't find any useful docs/examples on the `react-navigation` site regrading testing a screen. (I also googled a lot around)

I can try to boil down the code to something like this:

> App.json

```
...

export default function App() {
...
return (
 <Provider store={store}>
   <Navigation />
 </Provider>
)
}
```

> Navigation.js

```
import React from "react"
import { NavigationContainer, DarkTheme } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack"

import BottomTabNavigator from "./BottomTabNavigator"

export default function Navigation() {
  const navigationRef = React.useRef(null)

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      theme={DarkTheme}
      ref={navigationRef} // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#ref
    >
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

> BottomTabNavigator

```
import React from "react"
import { Linking, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from "react-native"
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons"

import Profile from "src/screens/profile"
import SignIn from "src/screens/sign-in"

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const TabIcon = ({ name, color }) => <Feather name={name} color={color} size={20} />

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: Colors.defaultWhite,
        style,
      }}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabIcon name="user" color={color} />,
          title: I18n.t("components.tab_navigator.profile"),
        }}
      />
  )
}

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator()

function ProfileNavigator() {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: please share expo link

Comment: I don't have the permission from my client to share the source code. @Chandan do you  have a good link to an example code that does it?

Comment: please share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self-contained%20correct%20example.) of code

Comment: Arhh.. Will try to make an expo snack later today

Comment: you don't need to share client code just create some example expo.